# Conflicto al redireccionar pagina linea 1 sidebar.php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Resulta que estoy tratando de hacer una redirección después de que hago un registro de un nuevo usuario en mi página, pero resulta que me sale el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según esa imagen me está diciendo que en la línea 1 del sidebar.php me esta generando un conflicto, ese archivo lo comento de mi index y me funciona perfectamente el HEADER, no se que pueda ser el error, si alguien de ustedes sabe que es el error le agradeceria que me ayudara.

Les dejo el codigo del index y el sidebar

index.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'autoload.php';
require_once 'config/db.php';
require_once 'config/parameters.php';
require_once 'views/layaout/header.php';
require_once 'views/layaout/sidebar.php';

function show_error(){
     $error = new ErrorController();
     $error->index();
}

$controlador = new UsuarioController();
if(isset($_GET['controller'])){
 $nombre_controlador = $_GET['controller'].'Controller'; 
}elseif(!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
    $nombre_controlador = controller_default;
}else{
   show_error();
}
if(class_exists($nombre_controlador)){
    $controlador = new $nombre_controlador();
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && method_exists($controlador, $_GET['action'])){
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        $controlador->$action();
    }elseif(!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
        $action_default = action_default;
        $controlador->$action_default();
    }else{
       show_error();
    }
}else{
    show_error();
}
require_once 'views/layaout/footer.php';
?>
```

sidebar.php

```html
<!--BARRA LATERAL-->
<aside id="lateral">
    <div class="block_aside" id="login">
        <h3>Entrar a la web</h3>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" />
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" />
            <input type="submit" class="bt_send" value="Enviar"/>
        </form>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Mis pedidos</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Gestionar pedidos</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Gestionar categorias</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
<!--CONTENIDO CENTRAL-->
<div id="central">
```

el header que uso es este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>CALLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            </header>
            <!--MENU-->
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Categoria 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Categoria 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Categoria 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Categoria 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Categoria 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="content">
```

Y estos archivos los llamo desde mi archivo de index el cual ya se los compartí al principio. Agradezco mucho la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Puse en practica lo de poner el session_start(); en el header.php y el aside.php, pero como ya había iniciado la sesión en el index.php me sale que ya la sesión fue iniciada, después decidí dejar en el archivo del header.php y el aside.php y del lado del aside.php me volvio a salir el mensaje de que ya sesion esta iniciada, después alterne el inicio de la sesión primero en el header.php y después en el aside.php pero me seguia saliendo que error del principio, no se que mas pueda ser, agradezco mucho la ayuda que me puedan seguir dando.

Comment: ¿Tienes el archivo del header? El error sale al tener la línea uno como tú has dicho intentando modificar el header.

Comment: Si claro tengo el archivo, te lo comparto @jack More???

Comment: Si intenta compartirlo a ver si podemos solucionarlo. Añade el código haciendo un (editar) en tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola @Jack More, ya comparti el header que uso, como comente, llamo estos archivos desde mi index, pero el problema solo ocurre cuando llamo el sidebar después de crear un usuario, no mas borro todo el contenido del sidebar funciona perfectamente, agradezco la ayuda que me puedas dar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error se encuentra al no llamar `session_start();` antes en el archivo del `header`y del `sidebar.php`. Ya que si que lo llamas en el `index.php`.

Por eso intenta poner al principio de los dos archivos este código:

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Si el error persiste, intenta solo poner-lo en el `header` o solo en el `sidebar.php`
Si aún te sigue dando el mismo error, coméntame-lo, y si es un error diferente indica en el post que error te sale

Comment: Hola lo puse en los dos archivos tal como me dijiste, y me sali el error que ya había iniciado la sesión entonces tome la decisión de borrarlo del index y dejarlo en el header y el sidebar y me sale el mismo error y si lo dejo en cualquiera de los tres me sale el mismo error que al principio @Jack More

Comment: Cuando dentro del archivo sidebar.php tengo las etiqueta <aside></aside>, no hay problema, me redirecciona y no más pongo dentro de esas etiquetas un div me genera enseguida el error y si pongo cualquier otra etiqueta, me genera ese error

Comment: hola @Jack More use otra solucion que encontre en internet, no se que tan conveniente sea pero me funciono:
<meta http-equiv='refresh' url=http://localhost/Udemy/proyecto-php-poo/usuario/registro'>
Ya me redirige de nuevo a mi formulario de creación de usuario, pero la verdad no me siento muy cómodo usando esta instrucción como te dije no se que tan conveniente sea

Comment: @FamiliaValenciaHdz Viste la pregunta que te enlazaron, esa te soluciona el problema? O aún te sigue dando error?

Comment: Hola @Jack More, si soluciono mi problema, pero como te dije en el comentario de arriba me gustaria mas hacerlo con header, pero me doy cuenta que esta generando conflicto después de que agrego algo del <aside>, por el momento tome esa solución, pero reitero me gustaria usar mas el header location